# DLLImport does not find the dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++, iis

I used `DLLImport[absolute path of the C++ dll]` in my asp.net C# code to call a method that is inside a C++ dll.  And that works perfectly.

I then published the website on IIS and it says it cannot load the dll.

Can you please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a Native LoadLibrary to load the DLL from a specific location.   The below URL talks about how this can be done.

I am assuming you have the right permission set's available to work with unmanaged code, you use something on the lines of:

```
private static bool CanCallUnmanagedCode
{
 get
  {
  try
  {
    new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Unmanage dCode).Demand();
  }
  catch(SecurityException)
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
}

void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (CanCallUnmanagedCode)
    Label1.Text = "This page can call unmanaged code.";
else
    Label1.Text = "This page can NOT call unmanaged code.";
}
```

Where Label1 is :

```
<asp:Label id="Label1" Text="Label Control" runat="server"/>
```

Next thing is to check the bitness of you asp.net environment to ensure it matches you .dll... as x86 DLL cannot be loaded via a x64 environment.

[How to call C++ DLL from ASP.NET (C#) code?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eldar/archive/2006/09/22/how-to-call-c-dll-from-asp-net-c-code.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175

Comment: It returns true so "This page can call unmanaged code" is shown in VS and in IIS. Also 32Bit flag is set to true.  Dll is in the folder that I have permission on.  It is in the bin folder of the website where all other managed dlls are located.  VS webserver settings are different IIS and I don't know which setting is different because everything works in VS. Can you please suggest anything else?

Comment: Next, i would try using LoadLibrary via "[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName); " and use a physical path and see what the what number the IntPtr is IntpTR.ToInt32() IS.

Comment: Sory but I am bit lost. Should I add [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpFileName); and call LoadLibrary(fileName) in the C# method before calling the function of my native C++ Dll?

Comment: And pass in the absolute path of the dll in LoadLibrary(absolute path of the dll)?

Comment: Yes, the LoadLibrary call should be done before your native methods.   (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/LoadLibrary.html)

Comment: ok, done it. it returns 0 in VS. On IIS, it again shows the same error message with DllNotFoundException

Comment: Here is another example of using LoadLibrary - http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0520__Windows/UsingloadlibraryfromDll.htm

Comment: What is the value of IntPtr returned from LoadLibrary?

Comment: If you have set SetLastError=true, can also get the value arshal.GetLastWin32Error(); this with the error codes @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381.aspx should give us a further clue.   I suspect it is a permissions issue or a missing dependent DLL.

Comment: Now you need to invoke Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); and this will tell us more... 0 just says it has failed...

Comment: What confuses me is that 126 means "dependent dlls are missing".  If  the dependent dlls are missing then why does it work in VS and not in IIS?

Comment: It means the DLL requires other DLL's that are not on the PATH too, you can either use "dumpbin" to see the files dependencies or use a utility such as Dependency Walker 2.2 @ http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to find them.

Comment: from dependency walker, MSVCR90.dll has a yellow question mark and pointing to the path: c:\windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_none_50940634bcb759cb\MSVCP90.DLL but the files msvcm90, msvcp90 and msvcr90  are present there.

Comment: And the error messages from DependecyWalker is "Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found."

Comment: What is the value of IntPtr.Size?

Comment: So, it sounds like a x64 DLL is being picked up or a DLL found does not have the same expected export symbols. You might want to try installing the VS2008.. could be a VS2008 v VS2008 SP1 issue... try installing http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a5c84275-3b97-4ab7-a40d-3802b2af5fc2&displaylang=en

Comment: you know i found the solution. i recompiled the DLL and changed code generation in C++ settings of VS to MD and it started to work :-)

Comment: and I guess it started to use a different version of the C runtime... good one to remember..

Answer (score 1):

Would be very difficult to **guess**. Most likely causes are:

- Location does not exist
- Application Pool identity does not have access to the folder hence would not find the path.
- Some werid virtualization is going on the server.
- **AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers** attribute needs to be defined since the server could have a more stringent security involving P/Invoke.

First of all, I would look at the **Windows event log** -> Security and Application.

If I can run some tools on that server, I would run sysinternal's `ProcMon.exe` to see which paths it is looking into while trying to resolve the DLL path.

Comment: No luck.  Location exists. It's the bin folder where all dlls are located.  Application pool identity has access as it can access other dlls.  No virtualization on the server as the VS and IIS are on the same box.  How do I set AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute?